# What does this command mean?

Tags: linux

While installing QT, I met this command:

```
sudo -s chmod u+x QtSdk-offline-linux-x86_64-v1.2.1.run
```

I wonder what `-s` means here.And it seems similar here:

```
sudo -s ./QtSdk-offline-linux-x86_64-v1.2.1.run -style cleanlooks
```

Comment: Whenever you don't know what a command line switch does, your first stop should be the program's `man` page.  Do `man sudo`. With most pagers, you can then search for the flag by typing `/` and then your search pattern `-s`. Press `n` to skip to the next search match until you get to the flag's description.

Comment: This kind of questions should be addressed to [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) instead of stackoverflow.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Oh,thanks!I didn't realize it's a pattern of the `sudo` command!

Comment: @rsm OK!I didn't know that site before:(

Comment: I think you can find an answer here : [http://superuser.com/questions/306923/what-does-sudo-s-actually-do]

Comment: I think you can find an answer here: [http://superuser.com/questions/306923/what-does-sudo-s-actually-do](http://superuser.com/questions/306923/what-does-sudo-s-actually-do)

Answer (score 1):

sudo -s runs a shell with root privileges

Answer (score 0):

> "The -s (shell) option runs the shell specified by the SHELL
>   environment variable if it is set or the shell as specified in
>   passwd(5). If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for
>   execution. Otherwise, an interactive shell is executed."

From [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70534/difference-between-su-sudo-s-sudo-i).

As mentioned in the comments above, check out the man info:

1. Type `man sudo` to your command line.
2. Find -s in the list of commands for a good explanation.